# SQL, join workdate to pay rate by effective date

Tags: sql, join

I have 2 tables, one with employee work dates and one with pay rates for each employee and when those rates took effect.

They look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE pay_rates 
(
    [EMP ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RATE] [decimal](11, 6) NOT NULL,
    [EFFECTIVE DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE work_dates
(
    [EMP ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [WORK DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
)
```

The `pay_rates` table will have many entries for each employee as their pay was adjusted over the years.

The `work_dates` table contains dates each employee worked.

Both of these tables contain other information, but I've simplified down to the relevant columns.

I would like to join the two such that I can see the what the pay rate would have been on each work date. More technically I want to join each record in `work_dates` to a record in `pay_rates` where with the largest `EFFECTIVE DATE` that is less than the `WORK DATE` and where the `EMP ID` matches.

Comment: That is invalid standard SQL.Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps when you join `pay_rates` to `work_dates`, you could use `not exists` to require that no rate exists whose effective date is on or before the work date *and* is strictly after the effective date of the rate to which you're joining. Something like this:

```
declare @pay_rates table (
    [EMP ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RATE] [decimal](11, 6) NOT NULL,
    [EFFECTIVE DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL
);

declare @work_dates table (
    [EMP ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [WORK DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL
);

insert @pay_rates values
    (1, 10.25, '20160615'), 
    (1, 10.65, '20170101'), 
    (1, 11.85, '20180101');
insert @work_dates values 
    (1, '20160701'), 
    (1, '20170101'), 
    (1, '20170701'), 
    (1, '20171231'), 
    (1, '20180102');

select
    WorkDate.[EMP ID],
    WorkDate.[WORK DATE],
    Rate.RATE,
    Rate.[EFFECTIVE DATE]
from
    @work_dates WorkDate
    inner join @pay_rates Rate on
        WorkDate.[EMP ID] = Rate.[EMP ID] and
        WorkDate.[WORK DATE] >= Rate.[EFFECTIVE DATE] and
        not exists
        (
            select 1 
            from @pay_rates LaterRate 
            where
                LaterRate.[EMP ID] = WorkDate.[EMP ID] and
                LaterRate.[EFFECTIVE DATE] <= WorkDate.[WORK DATE] and
                LaterRate.[EFFECTIVE DATE] > Rate.[EFFECTIVE DATE]
        );
```

I have assumed here that you do not allow two pay rates to have taken effect on the same date for the same employee. In that case, the above query would give you two results for each work date that uses those rates, since it has no way to prioritize one over the other.

Comment: This seems to work. Still need to go through and verify a few records by hand. I always forget I can do exists and not exists.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
SELECT pr2.[emp id], pr2.rate
FROM pay_rates pr2
INNER JOIN
(SELECT wd.[emp id], MAX(pr.[effective date]) AS mx_date
 FROM work_dates wd
 LEFT JOIN pay_rates pr
 ON (wd.[emp id] = pr.[emp id] AND wd.[work date] > pr.[effective date])
 GROUP BY wd.[emp id]) sub
ON pr2.[emp id] = sub.[emp id] AND pr2.[effective date] = sub.mx_date
```

In the sub-query, select the largest effective day per emp id that is less than the employee's work date. Then join the result back to the pay rates table to pull in the rate.